# Why creation of Apex Trigger on Change Event for Custom Setting fails if it is available in the picklist?

Tags: trigger, error, customsetting, gack, change-data-capture

Change Event for Custom Settings is available in the picklist to create Apex Trigger, but when you try to create an Apex Trigger on that, it fails. Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have opened a case in Salesforce Support and [confirmed this is a problem](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V000002iPTw)

CDC events should not be supported for Custom Settings and shouldn't appear in the picklist.

They have published a known issue for this.

Comment: it'd be great to note what the problem is - that they are not supported for CustomSettings and shouldn't appear in the picklist.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer